# autolayout adding extra space from top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have added `PageControl` in my App. On my first page, I have `UIImageView` &  `UILabel`. But I don't know it is adding some extra space from top. Please tell me why this happening.

**Label constrinats:**

[image: label]

**ScrollView constraints**

[image]

**ImagevIew constraints**

[image]

**Result**
[image]

Comment: I have already done that but it does not work for me

Comment: try setting label's top to superview

Comment: Already done that.Vertical space to top layout guide

Comment: Yes, the labels top constraint must be set the supverview's top, not the top layout guide as you have.  Delete that constraint, drag the label above the layout guide then set the constraint to the supverview's top, not the layout guide

Comment: @DheerajKumar: top layout guide and superview are different. Do as Paulw said.

Comment: I don't see an option for superview.I am seeing only top layout guide here

Comment: View controller insetting scroll view automatically?

Comment: No.I have added a scrollview for that

Answer (score 0):

Try these constraints

**Label**

[image]

**ScrollView**

[image]

**ImageView**

[image]